# how to know device is power off

Tags: android

I want to do something when the mobile device is closing, but I don't know what is the method; could you tell me how to detect if mobile device is shutting down?
 
I know the method about mobile restart `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`, but I cannot find similar power off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN

> public static final String
>   ACTION_SHUTDOWN
>
> Since: API Level 4 Broadcast Action:
>   Device is shutting down. This is
>   broadcast when the device is being
>   shut down (completely turned off, not
>   sleeping). Once the broadcast is
>   complete, the final shutdown will
>   proceed and all unsaved data lost.
>   Apps will not normally need to handle
>   this, since the foreground activity
>   will be paused as well. This is a
>   protected intent that can only be sent
>   by the system.
>
> Constant Value:
>   "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"

This would appear to be it? I just Googled your command and it was on the Standard Broadcast Actions list. :)

Comment: HTC being HTC they use a different flag, you'll need both:  
  
  
<receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver">  
<intent-filter>  
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />  
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />  
</intent-filter>  
</receiver>