# Android: shutdown broadcast receiver emulator vs. real device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver, on the emulator (API Level 10) everyhting works fine. A http message is sent to a server as a prove. When running the app on a real device (2.3.5 HTC) this doesn't work. I am not getting this http message, nor (if device connected via USB) I see a message in LogCat. My feeling is that the receiver is not being sent at all. Does anyone have an idea how to analyze?

The code is most basic:

```
public class ReceiverShutdown extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    @Override   
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {       
    Log.v("My App", "System going for shutdown.");//emulator shows this
    DataTransfer.sendErrorMessage("99", "Recievershutdown being sent"); //emulator shows this

     //do what I really want to do here     
    }

}
```

Comment: in stead of voting down it would be nice to leave a comment what unclear is. Thanks.

Comment: I think showing the actual code of the receiver would be great. Also what broadcast you are trying to catch. Also your details are a bit unclear, when you say that you don't have any message in your logcat, does this mean that you put a log statement in the receiver and don't see that executed, or that you wait for the system to show a message? EDIT: Ops, should look at the title.

Comment: Actually searching for a minute gave me this result: HTC uses a different broadcast for the shutdown, named `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076410/how-to-know-device-is-power-off) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227791/how-can-i-handle-action-shutdown-event-on-htc-desire-for-power-off-option). So I guess no research effort applies as well.

Comment: thanks. Problme solved. I am quite surprised to hear that HTC can change the API in such a way. Does someone know a good resource where these incompatible changes are listed?